# How to make a LayerDrawable (layer-list item) invisible on Android?

Tags: android, view, visibility, layer

I have defined a layer-list with a couple of items on an xml file.
The items are displayed o.k.
I want every five second or so one of the layers to become invisible.

It works o.k. for a simple textview for example but not for the Layer inside the LayerDrawable

```
final private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        LayerDrawable myDrawable= (LayerDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.all_layers);
        Drawable layer =  myDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.interesting_layer);
        if (layer.isVisible()==true)
        {
            layer.setVisible(false, false);
        }
        else
        {
            layer.setVisible(true, false);
        }
        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTest);
        if (txt.getVisibility()==0)
        {
            txt.setVisibility(4);
        }
        else
        {
            txt.setVisibility(0);
        }
        handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
    }
};
```

Do I try to get the Id of the layer in a wrong way (I found it from here...)?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I did that playing with the alpha of the layer. This code will make your layer disappear:

```
layer.setAlpha(0);
```

And then you can display it again with:

```
layer.setAlpha(255);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: yeah, it totally helps but why setVisible(false, false) not working? In my specific case i need to hide one of the drawables, so i'm trying to execute layerDrawable.getDrawable(1).setVisible(false, false); - why this isn't working?

Comment: Odd. Because of this, I've reported here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/127538945

Comment: I don't know why, but setAlpha to 0 in my case leaves a gray background =(

Comment: @yeyeyerman, Thanks, this one helped me in 2024. Still layer.setVisible doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Setting the background tint as transparent gave me the desired output in my case

```
layer.setTint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

I tried using the
`isvisible()` function however it wasn't working for some reason